# How can the oscillation of a dish be represented with an equation?

Tags: physics

I am reading the book [Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surely_You%27re_Joking,_Mr._Feynman!) and I got to the point where he is eating lunch in the canteen when someone throws a dish and he thinks about the equation which represents its oscillation. I got curious about it. What is the equation in real conditions and in ideal ones? (I'm a high school student)

Comment: Not everything in this book really happened. If it happened, you will be able to find it on the Internet through a proper search.

Comment: @KBS I mainly find information about Hooke's law when I search on the Internet. I wanted something more related to the anecdote in the book, like the explaination of the rotation of an object while oscillating

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Disk?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @KBS thank you!